# EXCEL How to check if Column A contains specific value and Column B contains 2 specific values?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

On my excel spreadsheet, I need to check if Column A contains the value "check" and if Column B contains the value "900" and/or "1185". If Column B contains either value, I want those values displayed on Column C.

This is the code I used, but it does not work:

```
=IF(AND(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("check",B4)),ISNUMBER(SEARCH("900",C4))),ISNUMBER(SEARCH("1185",C4))),C4,"N")
```

I need to use the `ISNUMBER` formula and not the "=" formula because "check" is just a part of the value in Column A. The actual value in Column A is something like this: "Example CHECK #3248". So I need to use the ISNUMBER. Column B only contains numbers. So only something like "900.00" for each line.

I am not sure what syntax I'm supposed to use or how to correctly write this. Can someone please help me with this code? Thank you

Comment: Are the values in column B just numbers, or some text that may contain those numbers e.g. `PART NO 900` or `THING 1185 STUFF` etc ?

Comment: Column B only contains numbers. So only something like "900.00" for each line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're looking for the string `CHECK` in the cells in column A then you can use:

`=IF(AND(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("CHECK",A4)),OR(B4=900,B4=1185)),B4,"")`

E.g.

[image]

Comment: Sorry, I should've mentioned earlier, but I need to use the ISNUMBER formula and not the "=" formula because "check" is just a part of the value in Column A. The actual value in Column A is something like this: "Example CHECK #3248". So I need to use the ISNUMBER.

Comment: Then adjust the `OR(`-part to `OR(ISNUMBER(condition1),ISNUMBER(condiotion2))`

Answer (score 0):

`AND` shall be used only when all conditions are binding. In your case, the check is sequential i.e. IF column B condition is true only then the next column needs to be checked so the formula shall be altered like below.

`=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("check",B4)),IF(OR(C4=900,C4=1185),C4,"N"),"N")`